# how to get c++ man pages on os x?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, vim, manpage

In Ubuntu, after install libstdc++6-x.x-doc, docs are available via man, for example for libstdc++-4.8-doc:

```
man std::list
man std::weak_ptr
man std::ios_base
```

Is it possible to install man pages for c++ (using brew or any other means) on OSX?  The reason for specifically requiring man pages is so that I can access them from vim using `SHIFT-K`.

Note: I'm using the XCode version of g++:

```
snowch$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install those man pages from [here](https://github.com/jeaye/stdman). Just run the following commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jeaye/stdman
$ cd stdman
$ ./configure
$ make install # as a user with appropriate permissions to install
```

Comment: to get `man -k` to work afterwards, you'll also need to do `/usr/libexec/makewhatis $MANPATH` as a user w/ appropriate permission.

Comment: On Mac, `brew install cppman` and then (for example) `cppman std::vector`.