# How to install documentation for c++ in xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, code-documentation

When using Swift or Objective-C in Xcode, Xcode provides a Quick Help tool in the Utilities section and by option-clicking something in your code. That way you can see some documentation about the thing you're clicking on.

Is there a way to make this also work for C++? (Or another IDE that does something similar, I'm not really bounded to Xcode.)

**[Option-click]**

[image]

**[Quick-help]**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I love this question. I had the same question for C wih xCode.  An alternative solution, use `man` on terminal to find out about a C API.  `man` pages are excellent for C APIs.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on how to use man? It asks me "What manual pages do you want?". What to do next? (An example would help maybe)

Comment: C++ man pages are not installed by default on MacOS or with xCode Command line tools.  Whereas C man entries are installed.  To get C++ follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301363/how-to-get-c-man-pages-on-os-x?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Then you can use commands like: `man std::ostream` to find out about `cout` and related APIs.

Comment: With recent xcode version, this is not possible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175411/how-can-i-show-c-code-documentation-in-xcode-9-3/50246298